# Как добиться максимально быстрой многопоточности?

Tags: c#

как добиться максимально быстрой многопоточности при переборе паролей?

Comment: Точно так же, как и для любой числомолотилки. По потоку на ядро, и как можно больше ядер/процессоров/компьютеров. </thread>

Comment: @VladD, почему не ответом?:)

Comment: Смотря какой перебор... Если офлайн - то это одно, а если онлайн - то другое.

Comment: Перейти на чистый C, максимально вылизать всю криптографию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В виду отсутствия четкой формулировки вопроса, напишу общие рекомендации:

1. Продумать алгоритм работы программы с учетом исполнения в нескольких задачах (использование эффективного алгоритма позволяет зачастую принципиально повысить производительность);
2. Создание потока достаточно дорогая операция, поэтому для минимизации вычислительных затрат используйте ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => { SomeTask(); }) или Task.Run(), Parallel.Invoke(()=> SomeTask());
3. Если Вам необходимо дожидаться завершения задачи и получения каких-то результатов, выполнять продолжения (callbacks), обрабатывать исключения, то лучше всего воспользоваться Task Parallel Library основывающейся на System.Threding.Tasks.Task
4. Если задачи несложные, то объединяйте их в пакеты и в поток добавляете уже пакет;

Comment: а какой на ваш взгляд самый короткий кусок кода для обычного перебора паролей, самый короткий ?

Comment: @VladD может ты знаешь ?